# understanding joining a faust topic with a faust table and partitioning

Tags: python, apache-kafka, faust

I have two topics:

- 1 topic with event data (`EventData`, let's say **5 partitions**) -- logs on this topic use CustomerID as a key.
- 1 **compact** topic with enrichment data (`EnrichmentKVs`, let's say **3 partitions**) -- logs on this topic use the same CustomerID as a key.

The goal is to keep EnrichmentKVs in a Faust table and when EventData logs are streamed in, they are enriched with the data from that table and published to a new stream/topic.

So I have two **Faust** (python) applications, each with its own number of instances running:

- App1 (N-instances running) publishes to the EventData topic with the key=CustomerId
- App2 (M-instances running) does the following:

  - update the faust table (`EnrichmentKVsTable`) for values from EnrichmentKVs topic
  - stream-in from EventData topic and "join" the data from the Faust table with the data streaming from `Eventdata`

My understanding is that every instance of App2 will only have a partial Table of EnrichmentKVs based on the partitioning key. For the "JOIN" to work, any logs for `EventData(key="1234")` must go to the same App2 *instance* as the logs for `EnrichmentKVsTable(key="1234")`

How can Faust ensure this when the partitioning of the two input topics is different, and the number of instances of each application might also be different? Or am I approaching this problem wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Update (Kstreams info, non-faust):

- https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join
- https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/faust.tables.globaltable.html

Things Learned:

1. It looks like it IS a requirement that the JOINing topics must have the same number of partitions, and I'm assuming Faust has the same restriction. This explains my concerns above... *except*...
2. ... it also looks like there are Global tables in KStreams and a correlated feature in Faust 1.9+ (linked).

Hopefully this is a breadcrumb for the next person to run across a similar question to mine above.

Comment: Did you find answer? It looks like even in updated repo faust-streaming, joining is still not supported.